# POST create returning createdAt as null

Tags: java, quarkus

My domain entity code:

```
@Cacheable
@Entity
@Table(name = "core_application")
public class Application extends PanacheEntityBase {

    // ...

    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    public LocalDateTime createdAt;

}
```

My Data Transfer Object (DTO) code:

```
public class ApplicationDTO {

  // ...

  private LocalDateTime createdAt;

  // ...

  public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
      return this.createdAt;
  }

  public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
      this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }

  public ApplicationDTO(/** ..., */LocalDateTime createdAt) {
      // ...

      this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }

}
```

My resource endpoint code:

```
@Path("/responses")
@ApplicationScoped
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResponsesResource {

    final static int HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY = 422;

    @Inject
    ApplicationService applicationService;

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public ApplicationDTO getApplication(@PathParam(value = "id") UUID id) {
        ApplicationDTO entity = applicationService.getApplication(id);

        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Application with id of " + id + " does not exist.", Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return entity;
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response create(ApplicationDTO applicationDTO) {
        if (applicationDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Id was invalidly set on request.", HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }

        ApplicationDTO entity = applicationService.save(applicationDTO);

        return Response.ok(entity).status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
    }

}
```

The application service code

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationService {

    @Inject
    ApplicationMapper applicationMapper;

    public ApplicationDTO getApplication(UUID id) {
        return applicationMapper.toDto(Application.findById(id));
    }

    public List<ApplicationDTO> getAll() {
        Stream<Application> entities = Application.streamAll();

        return entities.map(entity -> applicationMapper.toDto(entity))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public ApplicationDTO save(ApplicationDTO applicationDTO) {
        Application entity = applicationMapper.toEntity(applicationDTO);

        entity.persist();

        return applicationMapper.toDto(entity);
    }

}
```

When submit the POST request, `createdAt` is return as null:

[image]

[image]

But if I run GET request, `createdAt` is returning correctly:

[image]

[image]

Where I do the mistake?

Comment: We do not see the relevant code in `ApplicationService#save`. You mention the entity `Application` but it is not used in the code you shared. Are you reassigning the entity after saving it to the database?

Comment: First, thanks @Matt! I updated the question putting the application service code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@CreationTimestamp` value is assigned when the entity is inserted into the database.

In your case, this happens at the end of the transaction.
Since your `@Transactional` annotation is placed at your controller method, you create your DTO before the transaction is committed and when the timestamp is still `null`.

You might consider to move the `@Transactional` annotation to your service-method, or to use `entity.persistAndFlush()` to trigger an immediate insert, so that the timestamp is created before you create your DTO.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot for the explanation. Now I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your post method create object for timestamp.

I also face this kind of problem in mypast. Also change creation to temporal(temporaltype.timestamp).

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/add", produces = "application/json", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<ConfigImpact> addImpact(@RequestBody ConfigImpact impact) {
        Date mUpdatedDate = new Date();
        impact.setIsActive(true);
        impact.setLastModifiedTime(mUpdatedDate);
        impact.setModifiedUserID(1000);
        repository.save(impact);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(impact, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```